# Wrong version of mscorlib being added by build after upgrade (An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format)

Tags: jenkins, dll, msbuild, .net-4.6, mscorlib

I'm working on a project that was recently upgraded to Sitecore 8.2 and .NET framework 4.6 from 4.0. When I build it locally my site works, but in my testing environment, where I'm building in Jenkins using msbuild, the mscorlib dll is causing is causing a compilation error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'file:///E:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\Website\bin\mscorlib.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

There is no reference to mscorlib in my project, as this dll is referenced automatically by the build system, so I'm not sure how to modify or update it.

The line in the MSBuild logs where it's being added:

```
Copying file from "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" to "bin\Release\mscorlib.dll".
```

Furthermore, when I build my project in Visual Studio, it does NOT copy mscorlib.dll into my bin, so I'm not sure why this is happening in the Jenkins build and not my local environment.

Comment: `mscorlib` or any other .NET Framework system assemblies should never be copied to `bin` folder. What forced you to do so?

Comment: It's automatically being copied in MSBuild. I've been trying to figure out how to prevent that from happening but don't know how. It doesn't copy to my local bin folder when I build in Visual Studio but in Jenkins it gets copied.

Answer (score 0):

By default it was adding the dll from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ and I needed it to use the version in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework65\v4.0.30319\ instead. I added a reference to the csproj file with the correct path:

```
<Reference Include="mscorlib">
  <HintPath>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```